# How do I find the maximum integer in a list by mimicking the reduce function in Python?

Tags: python, list, integer, max, reduce

So this is what I came up with. I define one function to compute the maximum element in a list which works while the second function `myreduce` doesn't.

I don't understand why my logic is flawed. I'm new to programming. Help?

```
def maxoflist(l):       #function to compute the maximum element in a list
    maxi=l[0]
    for i in l:
        if i>maxi:
            maxi=i
    return maxi

def myreduce(myfunc,mylist): #this is where I'm trying to mimic the 
    res=[]                   #reduce function
    for i in mylist:
        res.append(myfunc(i))          
    return res
l=[1,2,3]
print(list(myreduce(maxoflist,l)))
```

Comment: Do you understand what the `reduce()` function does? Your `myreduce()` function does not do what `reduce()` does.

Comment: You could just use the builtin `max` function.

Comment: You have instead implemented the `map()` function here, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: @ruohola: sure, but then they'd not learn anything about loops or how `reduce()` works.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How do I mimic the reduce function?

Comment: Have a look at [docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for code comparison.

Comment: @ShrenikRaj: have you read the [`reduce()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)? Or were you looking for the [formal definition of the higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))?

Comment: @RoadRunner an explanation please?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've gone through the formal documentation and the way it works really seems too technical at this point. Can you please explain how I should try to mimic the reduce function

Comment: @ShrenikRaj I honestly would step through it on a piece of paper. Once you understand how it works, the code in the documentation becomes trivial.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't implement the reduce function. Your `myreduce()` function instead implements the [*map* higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)), producing a sequence of `myfunc()` results for the inputs in `mylist`. When mapping, the function used should take a single input, and each input is processed independently, and the resulting sequence of outputs are given in the same order as the inputs that produced them.

The [higher-order *reduce* operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) would produce a *single output*. Reducing means you iteratively take the output from the *preceding* reduce operation, and together with the next input value, the function is called to produce the next output. So the function takes *two* inputs for the reduce operation to work correctly. For the first step, where there is no preceding output, you would either start with a fixed starting value, or just take *two* inputs from the input list. With each step producing new output, the previous output is discarded. You end up with a single output at the end.

Using reduce to produce the maximum for `[1, 2, 3]` can start with two inputs, and a simple function that determines the maximum of those two inputs. The procedure then takes the following steps:

- Take the first input, 1, as the starting 'output' value. If there are no further inputs, this would be the final result.
- Use the initial output, 1 from the previous step, and the next input value, 2, and call the function with both. The maximum of 1 and 2 is 2, so that's what the function produces as the first output result.
- Use 2 from the previous operation, and the next input, 3 to call the function again. The maximum of 2 and 3 is 3, so that's what the function produces as the new output.
- There are no more inputs, the output is 3.

Your reduce implementation would have to do the same:

- start with a given starting value for the 'output', or take the first value from the input list.
- for each value in the (remainder of the) input list, call the function with the last output and the value, and the return value replaces the output.
- When all values have been processed, return the output.

Python 3 has implemented this as [`functools.reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce), the documentation actually comes with a pure-python implementation you could copy directly.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This was incredibly helpful!